# If Statement in Bingo

Tags: java, if-statement, jtextfield

I Have a Bingo Game that when you when a chip matches a number on the board the JTextfield goes YELLOW
So for my BINGO Statement I wrote

```
                    if (B1.setBackground(Color.YELLOW) && I1.setBackground(Color.YELLOW)...){
                        System.out.println("BINGO");
                    }
```

But it's not working
Is there anyway to actually do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Read your logic description and compare it to your code.

Comment: It is very, very bad to use the data related to visuals in the code implementing the logic of the game. You should not decide the outcome based on the cell's color - instead, you should use whatever data that you used to decide to turn the cell yellow, and use the same logic to see who has won.

Comment: I used this:
if (dice == GArray[0]){
       G1.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
      }
and I don't know how else to create a BINGO Winner statement :l

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code structure should be:

```
if (a chip matches a number on the board) {
   set background color for JTextfield to yellow;
   System.out.println("BINGO"); // <---- if this what you require
}
```

Comment: Every time a chip is called it looks to the board and if it sees a matching number it turns that Number's Textfield to Yellow.

Now if I have a BINGO it would appear as a straight line of Yellow TextFields correct? How can I write an if statement that says if (this row is all yellow textfields) { Syso Bingo...}

Comment: @JavaScrub You shouldn't.  You should have a model of some kind which is a virtual concept of the board and the game.  The UI would then model this on the screen and you would use the model to make determinations of the state of the game, decoupling the areas of responsibility